# Consuming and publishing my WCF and MVC projects

Tags: deploying

I am a complete newbie. I am building my very first web application using a SQLServer 2008 database, WCF project and a MVC3 Project in Visual Studio 2010. My host is godaddy so I was trying to start with launching my MVC Project at Godaddy. This gave me so many problems, that I decided to forget about that for now and try to launch my site on my localhost. Now I have 2 problems:

First: Both my WCF and My MVC Projects have been published correctly after creating web sites in IIS and then publishing in Visual Studio using the publish method "Web Deploy" and marked as IIS applications. In the output box I then get the message "Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to some url (localhost:port/IIS-websitename) .......Publish is successfully deployed........." If I then go to the url mentioned above, I get the error "webpage cannot be found".

Second problem: After I published my WCF Project successfully, I thought I should be able to add a Service Reference in My MVC Project to this service in order to consume my WCF, but NO service is to be discovered in my "Add Service Reference" dialog box in Visual Studio!!

Can anyone please help me? I do not have a clue of these technologies (IIS, Web Deploying, etc) Just know how to create my web application. Sorry, if I come across stupid but I have been trying stuff of which I didn't even know what I was doing for 3 days now. So I'm begging for someone to take me by the hand and leading me through what I guess should be a very simple task.

Many MANY thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MVC application:

MVC as the name suggests works with Controllers. You should have a controller that has a method, lets say MainController with sayHi() method and that method displays your view which is index.cshtml. So the way you call it would be : localhost:port/MainController/sayHi (you might need to add the website name before the controller, depends on your configuration)

Regarding the WCF service:

Under your website location, you should have a file myservice.svc which contains this line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="my.service.namespace.MyService" %>
```

and your Web.config file should look something like this:

```
<service name="my.service.namespace.MyService"
           behaviorConfiguration="">
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint
      contract="my.service.interface.IMyService"
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" />
  </service>
```

Note that the service name in Web.config should be the same one as in myservice.svc.

Then to call the service you need to type : localhost:port/path/to/servicefile/MyService

So if myservice.svc sits under inetpub/www/test/myservice.svc, you call localhost:port/test/myservice

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for helping! Reg. MVC: yes, I have an Index.html, which is also reached when I debug instead of publish my site. Reg WCF: my address tag is:       <service name="WcfDealshoppen.WcfDSService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfDealshoppen.IDSService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

Comment: sorry, Regarding MVC: my view is called Index.cshtml

Comment: Do you have a controller with an action/method? you should point the url to that action: localhost:port/IIS-websitename/myaction

Comment: I don't see any file named App.config by the way. Only 'web.config'

Comment: Regarding MVC: If I go to the url the web deploy has returned, I receive the error: 'Server Error in Application "Default Web Site" HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.......' Whilst my web site in IIS is named "MvcDealshoppen". I think that is strange?! But Regarding the WCF: I just get plain: "Web page can not be found"